# Assignment of dbms_metadata.get_ddl to pl/sql variable fails

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, plsql, oracle-sql-developer

I have the followig script

```
declare
    v_tmp  CLOB;
begin
   v_tmp := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'FOO', 'BAR');
end;
```

Where `FOO` is the table's name and `BAR` is the name of the current user.
When I run the script I get:

```
06502. 00000 -  "PL/SQL: numeric or value error%s"
*Cause:    An arithmetic, numeric, string, conversion, or constraint error
           occurred. For example, this error occurs if an attempt is made to
           assign the value NULL to a variable declared NOT NULL, or if an
           attempt is made to assign an integer larger than 99 to a variable
           declared NUMBER(2).
*Action:   Change the data, how it is manipulated, or how it is declared so
           that values do not violate constraints
```

.
The value returned by `dbms_metadata.get_ddl` appears to be of type `CLOB` so why isn't the assignement statement working?

Answer (score 2):

`CLOB` is not the problem. You may have a special character somewhere in the table definition.

Above code works in general. But below is an exception, to reproduce your error:

```
begin
  execute immediate 'create table t1 (c1 varchar2(100) default ''' || chr(0) || ''')';
end;
/

desc t1

 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 C1                                                 VARCHAR2(100)

declare
    v_tmp  CLOB;
begin
   v_tmp := dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'T1');
end;
/
```

Which gives:

```
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
LPX-00217: invalid character 0 (U+0000)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5805
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 8344
ORA-06512: at line 4
```

The whole error message may reveal more, and I would check the specific table in the dictionary views (`ALL_TABLES`, `ALL_TAB_COLS`), and look for such "anomalies".

Comment: This is the create script generate by SQLDeveloper for that table: ```CREATE TABLE USERS 
(
  ID NUMBER(10, 0) NOT NULL 
, NAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, USERNAME VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, USER_ROLE VARCHAR2(255 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CREATED_AT TIMESTAMP(6) 
, UPDATED_AT TIMESTAMP(6) 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE APLICATIE 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS UNLIMITED 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
) 
NOPARALLEL;``` It appears to look ok.

Comment: And If I do have an escape character in my create query what can I do? Is escaping a valid option in plsql?

Comment: @cristid9 No error on this one. https://pastebin.com/bJsbdyXs

Comment: If I run this query `select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'USERS', 'STUDENT') from dual
` in SQLDeveloper I get the following error https://pastebin.com/buc9UMnq

Comment: Ok, this is very dumb but It worked after I've restarted sql developer.